# Goal checking in BFS

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I tried to implement BFS algorithm in JAVA based on what I study but I'm confused a little, I'm not sure if I'm checking if the node is goal or I'm adding nodes to explored list in the appropriate place. Here's the code:

```
frontier.add(nodes.getFirst());//node.isGoal is only true if the node is desired node
    if(frontier.getFirst().isGoal)//Checking if the root node is goal
    {
        explored.add(frontier.getFirst());
        prev.put(frontier.getFirst(), null);
        goalNode = explored.getFirst();
        frontier.poll();
    }
    while (!frontier.isEmpty())
    {
        currentNode = frontier.poll();
        explored.add(currentNode);
        for (Node node : currentNode.children) {//adding node children to fronier and checking if they are goal
            if (!frontier.contains(node) || !explored.contains(node)) {
                frontier.add(node);
                prev.put(node, currentNode);//mapping nodes to parent node to return sequence of nodes
                if (node.isGoal) {
                    goalNode = node;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to provide some more information on what you're trying to to (e.g. does `isGoal` mean it is a _possible_ target node or is it already what you are searching for? In `if (node.isGoal)` you seem to keep _one_ goal node but continue iterating over `frontier` - do you really want to keep only the last `goalNode` which could be deeper in the tree?) as well as some comments in your code on what you think you're doing there. And do you have any problems with your code like not getting the expected results? If so please post the input, the expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: I wish the edits are sufficient

Comment: I'm looking for the only one goal, doesn't the break get me out of loop?

Comment: It gets you out of the inner for-loop, not out of the while.

Comment: OK. Should I check the goal before for loop or it's correct here?

Comment: I'll post an answer based on how I understand your question so far. Give me a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how I understand your code it seems you're doing it wrong: you check the first node in your initial set (e.g. tree level) and if it is not the goal node you add any children that are not already in `frontier` and that have not been visited yet. That's ok but probably unnecessary. What's wrong is that you're checking the child before checking any of the parent's siblings so your search is not exactly breadth-first.

So what could/should you do?

Let's assume your data represents a tree (breadth-first indicates that) and you're starting at some level (e.g. the root node). Since the data is a tree in a breadth-first approach any child not cannot have been visited already and is also probably not in your `frontier` list so there's no need to check for that (if you have a more general graph that might not be the case).

Thus the algorithm could look like this:

```
LinkedList<Node> frontier = new LinkedList<>();

//assuming you always have a root node just add it
frontier.add( root );

Node goal = null;

//loop until the list is empty, if we found a goal node we'll break the loop from the inside
while( !frontier.isEmpty() ) {
  //get the node at the start of the list and remove it
  //in the first iteration this will be the root node
  Node node = frontier.pop();

  //found a goal so we're done
  if( node.isGoal ) {
    goal = node ;        
    break; //this breaks the while loop
  }

  //didn't find a goal yet so add the children at the end
  if( node.children != null ) {
    frontier.addAll( node.children );
  }
}
```

Doing it this way means you add the nodes of the next level (children) at the end and pop the nodes higher up the tree from the front until you've found what you're searching for. That means you should always have only one or two levels of your tree in the list, i.e. the current level as well as the immediate children of any already processed current level node.

As you also can see there's no need to keep a `explored` set since we're operating on a tree.

Additionally you might want to think about whether you really need to build that `prev` map during iteration since you might have to remove elements again and a map is not really suited to get the path from your goal node to the root. You might want to keep a link to the parent in each node instead and thus once you've found the goal node you'd just iterate up until you reach the root.